# Dimension of a subspace of $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^4)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V = \{f \in \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^4) \mid f(x,y,z)=f(z,x,y)\}.$
>
> Find $\dim_\mathbb{R}(V)$.

I think I need to use the dimension theorem for vector spaces: I need to find a  linear transformation from $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^4)$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ which has kernel equal to $V$ and image equal to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Also I looked at how $f$ behaves at base of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but I get nothing. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you have a linear transformation $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^4) \to \mathbb{R}^3$, it cannot have image $\mathbb{R}^4$. Maybe you meant a linear transformation which maps to $\mathbb{R}^4$ instead.

Comment: i edit it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. A linear transformation $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^4)$ is uniquely determined by its values on a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. In particular, if I take the standard basis $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, once $f(1, 0 , 0)$, $f(0, 1, 0)$, and $f(0, 0, 1)$ are specified, we know $f$ completely as $$f(x, y, z) = xf(1, 0, 0) + yf(0, 1, 0) + zf(0, 0, 1).$$

If $f \in V$, then it follows from the definition of $V$ that we have

\begin{align*}
f(1, 0, 0) &= f(0, 1, 0)\\ 
f(0, 1, 0) &= f(0, 0, 1)\\ 
f(0, 0, 1) &= f(1, 0, 0).\\ 
\end{align*}

That is, $f(1, 0, 0) = f(0, 1, 0) = f(0, 0, 1)$. So $f \in V$ is completely determined by the value $f(1, 0, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^4$. Now consider the map

\begin{align*}
\phi : V &\to \mathbb{R}^4,\\ 
f &\mapsto f(1, 0, 0).
\end{align*}

You should be able to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. Once you've done this, the dimension of $V$ follows immediately.